# An interesting Olympiad Geometry problem.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

The point P lies in the interior of $\Delta ABC$. A line is drawn through P, parallel to each side of a triangle. The line divides BC into three parts of length $a , a', a''$ (in that order); AB into three parts, lengths  $c, c', c''$ (in that order); CA into three parts length $b, b', b''$ (in that order) . Prove that $abc = a'b'c' = a''b''c''$ . [image]
This is one of those types of question which I have never encountered before.

I was not able to use Ceva's theorem as there were no Cevians, I could not understand how to apply a similarity argument here, as that is what I think might work.

Any solution is highly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Your labels do not correspond to the diagram.

Comment: @Matt i am sorry, i realised it after posting, I am editing it in just a minute

Comment: @Matt i have corrected it

Comment: It's just similar triangles. Set it up using a ternary plot, and it will fall out.

Comment: @CalvinLin what is the meaning of ternary plot

Comment: Since you have a term, try [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot).

Comment: @CalvinLin unfortunately I have not yet learned Barycentric coordinates. Is there an alternate way you know of?

Comment: Even in the current set up, you can easily get to $bc = b"c"$ and similar relationships using similar triangles. It should lead to the answer.

Comment: @MathLover Can you check those indices. I believe it should be $bc = b'c''$.

Comment: @Aditya_math You don't need to know barycentric coordinates. I've included whatever information you need about how to find a ternary plot.

Comment: @CalvinLin Sorry I got busy with something else and did not check further. I did it very quickly and possible, may have made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If the ternary plot of $P$ is $(x,y,z)$, with $x+y+z=1$, show that

$$xyz \times |AB| \times |BC| \times |CA| = abc = a'b'c' = a''b''c''.$$

---

The ternary plot of $P$ is given by:

- Let $D, E, F$ be the foot of the perpendiculars from $A, B, C$ to the respective sides.
- Let $P_A, P_B, P_B$ be the foot of the perpendiculars from $P$ to the respective sides.
- Then, $ x = \frac{PP_A } { AD} , y = \frac{ PP_B} { BE}, z = \frac{ PP_C}{CF}$.
- In addition, we can show that $ x+y+z = \frac{PP_A } { AD} + \frac{ PP_B} { BE} + \frac{ PP_C}{CF} = \frac{ [PBC] + [PCA] + [PAB ] } { [ABC ] } = 1$.

---

Now, show that

- $a'' = y \times |AB|$
- $ a = z \times |AB| $
- $a' = x \times |AB|$

And similar equations. Hence, the hint follows.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Triangle ABC]

Quadrilateral $AFPE$, $CHPG$ and $BDPI$ are parallelogram. Sides $PE$, $PF$, $PI$, $PD$, $PG$ and $PH$ are labelled accordingly.

$\triangle DPG\sim \triangle PEH\sim \triangle IFP$.

$\Rightarrow  \frac{a'}{a''}=\frac{b}{b'}=\frac{c''}{c}$ and $\frac{a''}{a}=\frac{b'}{b''}=\frac{c}{c'}$

$\Rightarrow  \frac{a'}{a''}=\frac{b}{b'}   \Rightarrow  a'b'=a''b$------------$(1)$

Also, $\frac{a''}{a}=\frac{c}{c'}       \Rightarrow c'=\frac{ac}{a''}$-----------$(2)$

Multiplying $(1)$ by $(2)$ gives, $a'b'c'=abc$-----------------$(3)$

$\frac{a''}{a}=\frac{b'}{b''}    \Rightarrow a''b''=ab' $-------------------$(4)$

Also, $\frac{b}{b'}=\frac{c''}{c}    \Rightarrow c''=\frac{bc}{b'}$----------------$(5)$

Multiplyng $(4)$ by $(5)$ gives,  $a''b''c''=abc$-------------------$(6)$

From $(3)$ and $(6)$, we get, $\boxed {abc=a'b'c'=a''b''c''}$

Answer (score 0):

**Outline :**

The three small triangles are similar to original triangle with similarity ratio $l,m,n$ respectively.

If the original triangle has sides $A,B,C$, the small triangles have sides $lA,lB,lC$, $mA,mB,mC$ and $nA,nB,nC$.

Also identify three parallelograms. Equating opposite sides, one can find all of $a,b,c,\ldots,b'',c''$. Substituting should conclude.

Here is another problem on same setting : [Determining the average area as the point $X$ varies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3930378/determining-the-average-area-as-the-point-x-varies/3930400#3930400)